# Run espresso test multiple times, the right way

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I am working with Espresso in android at the moment, and I have this test, which is clicking a button, populating my listView and then logging the execution time of the action.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class Test {

@get:Rule
val mActivityActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

@Test
@Throws(java.lang.Exception::class)

fun test_fetchData_populates_listView() {

    //Click the get_rec_articles button.
    onView(withId(R.id.get_rec_articles_btn)).perform(click())
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

    //check if the listView is created.
    onView(withId(R.id.rec_articles_listview)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))

    //check if items can be clicked.
    onData(CoreMatchers.anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.rec_articles_listview)).atPosition(0).perform(click())
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val loadTime = (end - start)

    Log.d("###### LOADTIME FOR FETCHDATA FUNCTION:", "" + loadTime + " MILLISECS ######")

    }
}
```

I would like to find a good way to call the test 50 times and then get the average load time. I could just run it manually 50 times and then calculate it, but I have several tests which I would like the average load times from.

I have read the question on the site about the same topic and tried the suggested solutions, but it didn't help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39420849/4520965.  The answer outlines how to run an androidTest multiple times.  You can derive the average time by dividing the total execution time by the repeat value that you pass.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue and as a result I've created a library to run Android UI tests multiple times. Might be useful in your case: https://github.com/stepstone-tech/AndroidTestXRunner

As far as the load time goes, after running tests there's a JUnit report created with times of each test being placed in a generated JUNit report XML. You could get those values and calculate an average based on that.